# Format time in angular js filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, filter

How can I reformat time 06:31:04 to display only hh:mm - 06:31

Have tried

```
$scope.date = '06:31:04';

<p ng-bind="date | date:'HH:mm'"></p>
```

but time not formatting

How should I make it, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution was to write a filter

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.filter('formatTime', function ($filter) {
return function (time, format) {
    var parts = time.split(':');
    var date = new Date(0, 0, 0, parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
    return $filter('date')(date, format || 'h:mm');
};
});




{{ '06:31:04' | formatTime }}
```

Comment: This works perfect to me, but in `return $filter('date')(date, 'h:mm')` I turn for `return $filter('date')(date, 'h:mm a')`

Answer (score 7):

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

```
<p ng-bind="date | date:"hh:mm"}}></p>
```

Besides I think the format of your date is wrong. Because

> JavaScript Date instance [...] represents a single moment in
>   time. Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of
>   milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

Example: 1288323623006. So your format is not recognizable for the filter.
Try:

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

If you want to convert a string in your given format to a date, try:

```
var dateElements = "06:31:04".split(':');
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(time[0]);
date.setMinutes(time[1]);
$scope.date = date;
```

Then you can format it with the filter.

Comment: have applied to my code

    $scope.date = '06:31:04';

    <p ng-bind="date | date:"h:mma"></p>

still getting '06:31:04'

Comment: thank you, yes it work with a new date. But i have output in this format 06:31:04, is there a way to reformat this?

Answer (score 0):

u can use the below simple example:

```
$scope.date=new Date();
```

now in the html we have:

```
    <h2>
        {{ today| date:'hh:mm'  }}
    </h2>
```